# Using new docks/dongles on old Macs?

Tags: macbook-pro, dock, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I have a fully speced out MacBook Pro 15" from 2015, which I love using. Since I have got too many sound equipments with firewire I still don't have the nerves to move to never Macs.

However I love the one cable world of Thunderbolt 3, and the new cheaper than ever dongles. Can I connect them to thunderbolt 2 port somehow? If I can, how should I proceed? Of course I am talking about dongles which has power supplies.

Cheers,
~bio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apple adapter is bi-directional and power pass through works well. You won’t have any issues other than being restricted to Thunderbolt 2 speeds. (Which should be an obvious limitation)

- Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter
- https://store.apple.com/xc/product/MMEL2AM/A

USB 3.1 to 2.0 works for data and lesser power, so that’s not a full featured as Thunderbolt. Most devices should work fine if they don’t need USB PD.